# C# just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box

Tags: c#, winforms, jit

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to create browser.
   at Xilium.CefGlue.CefBrowserHost.CreateBrowser(CefWindowInfo windowInfo, CefClient client, CefBrowserSettings settings, String url, CefRequestContext requestContext)
   at Xilium.CefGlue.WindowsForms.CefWebBrowser.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

My JIT debugging is already enabled like said here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a(v=vs.85).aspx

why I am getting this error. How to prevent getting this error? App works normally but I don't know why I get this errors and how to solve or remove it.

Comment: Its an unhandled exception. Run it in the debugger...

Comment: I don't think you want to solve this issue opening a debug session on customers' machine so IMO your problem is **why** that component throws an exception. You may try Xilium (is it component vendor?) support, do your own debugging or posting here more details.

Comment: Ugh, what an awful way to report such a gross error.  It is all open source, you'll have to debug it.

Comment: Please tell me this does not come up on the client machine!

Comment: You also need to enable additional JIT debugging for WinForms as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdcetka3(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: MSDN links are no longer working.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5hs4b7a6(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:

Just-In-Time debugging is a feature that launches the Visual Studio debugger automatically when a program, running outside Visual Studio, encounters a fatal error. Just-In-Time debugging allows you to examine the error before the application is terminated by the operating system. The Visual Studio debugger does not need to be running when the error occurs.

To enable/disable Just-In-Time debugging

In Visual Studio,

1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
2. In the Options dialog box, select the Debugging folder.
3. In the Debugging folder, select the Just-In-Time page.
4. In the Enable Just-In-Time debugging of these types of code box, select or clear the relevant program types: Managed, Native, or Script.

   To disable Just-In-Time debugging, once it has been enabled, you must be running with Administrator privileges. Enabling Just-In-Time debugging sets a registry key, and Administrator privileges are required to change that key.

and:

5. Click OK.

Check out these links for more information on JIT debugger. Also To enable/disable Just-In-Time debugging

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a.aspx

Step 2:

If in case Visual Studio is not installed, I would suggest you to disable script debugging in Microsoft Internet Explorer and check if the pop-up eliminates.

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. Click on Tools
3. Click internet options>> then advanced tab
4. Under browsing section>> uncheck "disable script debugging(both others and Internet Explorer) " and "display a notification about every script error".